# SFML Anti-Aliasing - lines look dotted and moving objects smear

Tags: c++, graphics, sfml, antialiasing

Several months ago I made a Fourier Transform program using SFML 2.0. I used anti-aliasing level 8 and it looked perfectly fine. Just recently however (not quite sure when the problem began since I have not touched it in a while), it seems to have broken.

Whenever I draw a line it looks dotted and whenever something moves, it flashes between two states and it doesn't completely clear after calling `window.clear()`. It's not just that program however. Anytime I use any level of anti-aliasing greater than 0, even in SFML 2.5.1, the same problem occurs.

Here is the some sample code which does not work as it should on my computer:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::Vertex line[2] = 
    {
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(0, 0)),
        sf::Vertex(sf::Vector2f(800, 0))
    };

    sf::ContextSettings settings;
    settings.antialiasingLevel = 8.0;
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test", sf::Style::Close, settings);
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        line[1].position.y += 1.0;
        window.clear();
        window.draw(line, 2, sf::Lines);
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When the line finishes sweeping, it looks like this:

[image]

As this used to not be a problem, I don't think it's SFML's fault. I am using Windows 10 and my computer uses an integrated Intel UHD Graphics 620 graphics card, both of which have not changed since before the problem started happening. On a side note, I have not noticed any other programs on my computer break, only the ones I made.

Comment: I don't think this is a code issue. Maybe updated video drivers, a changed graphics setting. Video card's drivers have an AA setting too.

Comment: I don't quite follow. Your poste code doesn't reflect what the linked image shows. Can you provide an image for the posted code?

Comment: The code shows a line, one end at the origin, and the other sweeping down the right side. Part of my problem is that fast moving objects don't get cleared from the screen when AA is on. The picture is what the window shows when the line has traveled down to the bottom corner.

Comment: As far as settings, I've been searching for a few days and I still haven't found anything regarding anti aliasing.